# how to split observable by a dynamic number of CounterSets and run each observable on different thread?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a unknown numbers of `CounterSet` (could be 2, 3, 10, etc) and would like to split my `observable` by number of `CounterSet` plus would like to run each `observable` on different threads. How to achieve this?

Below code has fix number of `observable` and all running within same thread,

```
var observable = PerfCounterObservable.FromFile(@"C:\Files\BasicPerfCounters.blg");

        var CounterSet1_observable = from a in observable
                      group a by new { a.Machine, a.Instance, a.Timestamp } into groups
                      from g in groups.Where(a => a.CounterSet == "CounterSet1")
                      select new
                      {
                          groups.Key.Machine,
                          groups.Key.Instance,
                          groups.Key.Timestamp,
                          Counters = g
                      };

        CounterSet1_observable.Subscribe(z => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", z.Counters.CounterSet + " : " + z.Counters.CounterName, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));

        var CounterSet2_observable = from a in observable
                                     group a by new { a.Machine, a.Instance, a.Timestamp } into groups
                                     from g in groups.Where(a => a.CounterSet == "CounterSet2")
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         groups.Key.Machine,
                                         groups.Key.Instance,
                                         groups.Key.Timestamp,
                                         Counters = g
                                     };

        CounterSet2_observable.Subscribe(z => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", z.Counters.CounterSet + " : " + z.Counters.CounterName, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GroupBy linq is like Rx "Filter". This will give you a stream of 'groupedobservable'. Subscribing to that stream, on each new groupedobservable, subscribe to that groupedobservable by using ObserveOn, which puts the observer on its own thread. The following code illustrates the scenario and can easily be adapted to your case above I think:

```
void TestGroupBy()
        {
            var source1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            var m = source1.
                GroupBy(x => { return x % 2 == 0; });

            m.Subscribe(
                v => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Subscribing to " + v.Key);
                    v.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default).
                    Subscribe(seq =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId+"   "+seq);

                        });
                }
                );
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this

Answer (score 1):

The answer Sentinel gave can be done without the inner subscription:

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .GroupBy(num => num % 2 == 0)
    .SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
    .SelectMany(group => group)
    .Do(num => Console.WriteLine($"Work done on thread: {CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} Num: {num}"))
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
    .Subscribe(num => Console.WriteLine($"Displayed on thread: {CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} Num: {num}"));
```

Also, `ObserveOn` is use to select the thread to subscribe on, so if you're displaying your results on a console app, it'll be fine, but try it in something like WPF and you'll get a nasty surprise.

Comment: This requires educational explanations.